# Using JSFL, pulling items out of a library using libraryPath

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, jsfl

I'm making a SWF panel to automate some file setup. I'm using the libraryPath JSFL command to point to some external libraries. How do I put an item from one of those external libraries onto the stage using JSFL?

I've tried:

```
fl.getDocumentDOM().library.addItemToDocument({x:0, y:0}, 'myItem');
```

Answer (score 1):

Isn't the libraryPath to SWC files as in compiled flex like libraries, not visual components swc files?

If you want to add component swcs, use the [`componentPanel`](https://web.archive.org/web/20080704054225/http://dynamicflash.com/jsfl/#ComponentsPanel) object:

```
fl.componentsPanel.addItemToDocument({x:0, y:200}, "User Interface", "Button");
```

Answer (score 0):

From Adobe's documentation :

```
var itemIndex = fl.getDocumentDOM().library.findItemIndex( "myItem" );
var theItem = fl.getDocumentDOM().library.items[itemIndex];
fl.getDocumentDOM().addItem( {x:0,y:0}, theItem );
```